# Apache 24 not serving PHP on FreeBSD 10

Tags: php, freebsd, apache-2.4

I've been at this for a few hours now. I cannot figure out WHAT is wrong with my configuration.  When I navigate to any php file (wordpress installation is the intent), it opens the file for **download** rather then rendering/serving it.

I built (in order) Apache24, PHP55, PHP55-extensions, mod_php5.

I added the following to httpd.conf

```
LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache24/libphp5.so
LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache24/mod_rewrite.so
```

and I also added index.php like so:

```
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
</IfModule>
```

When Apache starts, it starts without any errors or warnings and this is my entire error log:

```
[Sat Nov 22 10:28:53.125634 2014] [core:notice] [pid 17892] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/local/sbin/httpd -D NOHTTPACCEPT'
[Sat Nov 22 10:43:03.724529 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 17892] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sat Nov 22 10:43:03.883893 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 17995] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (FreeBSD) PHP/5.5.19 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Nov 22 10:43:03.883968 2014] [core:notice] [pid 17995] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/local/sbin/httpd -D NOHTTPACCEPT'
[Sat Nov 22 11:15:53.541441 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 17995] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sat Nov 22 11:15:53.746420 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 14477] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (FreeBSD) PHP/5.5.19 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Nov 22 11:15:53.746504 2014] [core:notice] [pid 14477] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/local/sbin/httpd -D NOHTTPACCEPT'
```

I've built, configured and reinstalled this multiple times now and I still can't figure out how to make it work.

If there is something else I can post to help, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next config:

```
LoadModule php5_module        libexec/apache24/libphp5.so

<IfModule php5_module>
    <FilesMatch "\.(php|phps|php5|phtml)$">
        SetHandler php5-script
    </FilesMatch>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
</IfModule>

<IfModule mime_module>

    ...

    AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
    AddType application/x-httpd-php        .php

    ...

</IfModule>
```

I hope this help.

Comment: @FredericoSierra That worked! Thank you! Now a few more follow up questions.  1)  Would you please explain why it worked?   2) Why on earth would the installation/setup be so difficult on  FreeBSD?

Comment: @SteveMustafa I'm no expert about FreeBSD, but you must add the new mime type in `<IfModule mime_module>` section. SetHandler directive forces all matching files to be processed by a handler, in this case php module. See also https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/is-freebsd-difficult-to-learn.41656/

Comment: @FredericoSierra Thank you very much, that helped.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't configure PHP module. DirectoryIndex requires nonexistent module `mod_php5.c`. Try the next config:

```
LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache24/libphp5.so
. . . . .
<IfModule php5_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I just tried that, same result.